# Tentativa de comparar valores de uma lista em uma função não gera o resultado esperado

Tags: python, funções, lista, lógica

Tenho uma função que recebe uma lista e dentro dela um laço de repetição com o objetivo de percorrer todas as posições e comparar o valor daquela determinada posição com o valor que vem por parâmetro:

```
def recebeListaVal(number, value):

    lista = number
    valor = value
```

Quando o laço `for` é executado e tento comparar os valores que estão passando no momento pela lista com o valor recebido por parâmetro, não entra na condição.

```
for i in range(len(lista)):    
    if valor == lista[i]:      
        print(f'{value} elemento encontrado na lista contendo: {lista[i]}')
```

Tentei realizar um "debug manual" usando print antes do `if` para saber se os valores estão atribuídos e constatei que sim. Contudo, o problema persiste, fiz a lista com ocorrências repetidas do número 4 para testar buscar ele mas não encontra porque não entra na condição. Abaixo estão as entradas para a função e a chamada da mesma:

```
L = ['1','4','3', '4', '5', '6','4']
val = int(input('Digite um valor para buscar na lista : '))

recebeListaVal(L,val)
```

Comment: O problema é que você está comparando um número (retornado pela conversão via `int`) com uma string (cada elemento da sua lista é uma string). Ou converta todos os elementos da lista para string ou compare-os com uma string. Além disso, permita-me questionar a necessidade disto: `lista = number; valor = value`. Outra coisa é que não precisa usar um `range` aí. Como listas são iteráveis em Python, você já pode percorrer diretamente pelos elementos, assim `for element in list: ...`. :)

Comment: Neste caso Luiz Felipe, não há necessidade das atribuições de lista e valor? Eu vou tentar melhorar o código e prestar atenção nessa questão da conversão int e str, voltarei aqui para dar um feedback, vlw!

Comment: Note a diferença desta lista:  `L = ['1','4','3', '4', '5', '6','4']` para esta: `L = [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4]` - No input você usa `int` , conforme o @LuizFelipe já disse. A comparação espera uma lista de números. Se por algum motivo não puder mexer na lista (se ela vier de uma origem que não tem como controlar) pode fazer isto também: `if valor == int(lista[i]):` efetivamente convertendo cada ítem em int.

Comment: @Bacco e @Luiz Felipe, com a conversão tudo se resolveu, agora está entrando no `if` e posso contar quantas vezes o valor foi encontrado! Gratidão!

Answer (score 0):

Sua função não entra no loop for uma vez que no `if` vc compara a variável `valor` do tipo `int` com o elemento `lista[i]` que no caso da lista criada por vc é uma String.

Um número com `'` em volta é lido como tipo String, portanto a lista

```
L = ['1','4','3', '4', '5', '6','4']
```

Guardou apenas os valores do tipo String, o que pode ser confirmado da seguinte maneira:

```
L = ['1','4','3', '4', '5', '6','4']
for i in L:
    print(type(i))
```

Retorno:

> <class 'str'
> <class 'str'>
> <class 'str'>
> <class 'str'>
> <class 'str'>
> <class 'str'>
> <class 'str'>

### **Correção**

Para a correção vc tem algumas opções, acredito que essas são as mais simples:

1. remover os `'` ao criar a lista, ficando da seguinte maneira:

   `L = [1,4,3, 4, 5, 6,4]`

Código final:

```
def recebeListaVal(number, value):

lista = number
valor = value

for i in range(len(lista)):    
    if valor == lista[i]:      
        print(f'{value} elemento encontrado na lista contendo: {lista[i]}')

L = [1,4,3, 4, 5, 6,4]
val = int(input('Digite um valor para buscar na lista : '))

recebeListaVal(L,val)
```

2. converter o tipo da variável para int, utilizando o método `int()` ao fazer a comparação
   (Substituir `lista[i]` por `int(lista[i]`):

   ```
   for i in range(len(lista)):
       if valor == int(lista[i]):      
           print(f'{value} elemento encontrado na lista contendo: {lista[i]}')
   ```

Código final:

```
def recebeListaVal(number, value):

lista = number
valor = value

for i in range(len(lista)):    
    if valor == int(lista[i]):      
        print(f'{value} elemento encontrado na lista contendo: {lista[i]}')

L = ['1','4','3', '4', '5', '6','4']
val = int(input('Digite um valor para buscar na lista : '))

recebeListaVal(L,val)
```

Espero ter ajudado

-v-

Comment: `range(len(lista` é desnecessário, basta `lista`.